# How to restore a Winform in design mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Today something bad happened with my Project and I lost my form (If I view Design) but if I start the program the form is Ok, with all items that I inserted before.

I've realized that Form1.cs is not with Form1.Designer.cs 
[image]

How can I restore the form in design mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open AudioPlayer.csproj in a TextExitor like notepad++ and find Form1.Designer.cs then you can add DependentUpon node:

```
<Compile Include="Form1.Designer.cs">
  <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

Based on your last comment there are two InitializeComponent methods, please verify both and remove the one of them.

Comment: They are now together but still have nothing in Design mode and now Visual Studio don't compile   https://i.imgur.com/MmVUuAD.png

Comment: You have two InitializeComponent method, plz verify both and remove the one which is outside of Form1.cs file

Comment: I only found InitializeComponent method in Form1.Designer.cs. Maybe I Should start doing the project again. Thanks for your help anyway ! :)

Comment: @DanielPereira plz accept my answer if you found it helpful :). need scores